# Simulink: Apply mask parameters using command line

Tags: matlab, simulink, mask

I have a simulink masked block, I can open the mask using `open_system(gcb)` and I can close it using 'close_system(gcb)`.

However, any unsaved parameter will be erased.
Is there any way to ensure mask parameters are saved ? Like, clicking on Apply button or OK button ?

My matlab version is 2011b, the Simulink.Mask framework is not available in this version.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution:

First you have to get the block dialog:

```
function blockDialog = getBlockDialog( blockHandle )

    blockDialog    = [];
    allOpenDialogs = DAStudio.ToolRoot.getOpenDialogs;

    for index = 1:length( allOpenDialogs )

        dialogSource = allOpenDialogs( index ).getDialogSource;

        if isa(dialogSource, 'Simulink.SLDialogSource')
            dialogSourceSID = Simulink.ID.getSID( dialogSource.get_param('handle') );

            if isequal(dialogSourceSID, Simulink.ID.getSID( blockHandle ))
                blockDialog = allOpenDialogs( index );
                break;
            end
        end
    end            
end
```

Second you have to get the block widget:

```
function blockWidget = getBlockWidget( blockDialog)

    blockWidget = [];

    if ~isempty( blockDialog )
        blockWidget = DAStudio.imDialog.getIMWidgets( blockDialog );
    end
end
```

And last you perform the wanted action on the dialog using the widget:

```
function clickBlockOk( blockHandle )

    blockDialog = getBlockDialog( blockHandle );
    blockWidget = getBlockWidget( blockDialog );

    if ~isempty(blockWidget)
        blockWidget.clickOk( blockDialog );
    end

end

function clickBlockApply( blockHandle )

    blockDialog = getBlockDialog( blockHandle );
    blockWidget = getBlockWidget( blockDialog );

    if ~isempty(blockWidget)
        blockWidget.clickApply( blockDialog );
    end

end
```

In the widget you can find others functions like clickHelp, clickRevert, clickCustomButton.

What is really weird is that you need the dialog to get the widget but you still need the dialog to interact with it using the widget .... this is something that I do not get architecturally, but there's maybe a reason about it.

Answer (score -2):

You can set (and save) your parameters directly from the command line using `set_param`:

```
set_param('<path-to-your-masked-block>','<name-of-the-parameter-to-set>','value')
```

Note that the value argument must be passed as a string.

An easier way to do this is to set a variable in your mask that you can define directly from your workspace.

Comment: Thank you but this is not what I am looking for. I need to apply the value.
While using variables would do the trick it would be a workaround because no actual change would be done on the mask. One does not test a system using workaround

Comment: I probably do not understand your problem. If you use `set_param` the value will be saved provided that you don't open the mask first. If you're looking for a way to programmatically click on the Ok button after setting the parameter, I believe that there is no way to do that using Matlab 2011a but I can look into it. If you're interested in opening the window, changing the data (either manually or programmatically) and closing the window just to show how it is done you can easily "fake" the process getting the data when the mask is open and setting the data when the mask dialog is closed.

Comment: For specific reasons, the mask needs to be open, and I am not into faking processes. In this particular case, it would be actually impossible to manage and the code would be disgusting.

I found a solution however.

Comment: Of course when I wrote "fake" I was assuming that you needed to show how it is done, like in an education video or something like it. If you found a solution on 2011a, it would be nice to share it.